# How do I unfollow my own question?

Tags: support, follow-post

There seems to be a "follow" button in other people's posts that I can click on and receive notifications from. However, I seem to always receive notifications for my own questions without the ability to unfollow them. (The "follow" button is replaced by a "delete" button respectively.)

As a comparison, on GitHub, you can watch/unwatch a repository (which determines whether you receive notifications from that repository). You are initially watching your own repository, but you have the ability to unwatch your repository.

Given that I don't want to receive any notifications from my own questions, what should I do? (This isn't necessarily disassociation, I need to be able to receive reputation from upvotes/people need to know that it was me who posted this question.)

Comment: If you "need" the rep, you also have to take the curatorial responsibility.

Comment: @gnat no that is not a duplicate. This one is about not wanting any notification. Disassociating the post from the account is just a workaround, like treating a wound in the hand by chopping the hand: there is no hand, so there is no wound.

Comment: So I imagine you are uninterested in hearing comments about your question,  how they can be improvved or in requests for clarification. Just don't take away the rep...

Comment: a'_', write a question tagged with script request on this site: https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/script-request - maybe someone knows of a script or will write one to accomplish what you asked for.

Answer (score 14):

You can't unfollow your own questions. After all if you're not interested in their answers or responding to comments asking you to clarify the question, why did you ask it in the first place?

Once a question ages it will likely not get many comments anyway so though you may not be interested in those questions any more it's also rare that you'd get much in the way of messages about them.

If you truly aren't interested in your question any more you can aways delete it (subject to some restrictions if it's been answered).